# Math with multiple form input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, math

I'm a novice at jQuery. I'm building this form: http://vaniahardy.com/practice/testform.php

I've gotten it to multiply the unit price by the quantity to display the total on each line, and show the subtotal at the bottom.

Here are the values I need help displaying:

- Subtotal + 11%
- Total (Subtotal + 11% - Discount [a numeric value])

If you hit "Submit," the form emails me all the right values via PHP. I just want to also show them dynamically.

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".itemline input").keyup(multInputs);
   function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       // Action for each row
       $("tr.itemline").each(function () {
           // get the values from this row:
           var $qty = $('.qty', this).val();
           var $price = $('.price', this).val();
           var $total = ($qty * 1) * ($price * 1)
           $('.lineTotal',this).text($total);
           mult += $total;
       });
       $("#subTotal").text(mult);
   }
});
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead><tr>
<th>Item Number</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr class="itemline">
<td><input type="text" name="itemNum1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty1" class="qty" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amt1" class="price" /></td>
<td><span class="lineTotal">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="itemline">
<td><input type="text" name="itemNum2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty2" class="qty" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amt2" class="price" /></td>
<td><span class="lineTotal">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="itemline">
<td><input type="text" name="itemNum3" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty3" class="qty" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amt3" class="price" /></td>
<td><span class="lineTotal">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><b>Subtotal</b></td>
<td><span id="subTotal">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><b>Subtotal +<br />Shipping (5%) & Sales Tax (6%)</b></td>
<td><span id="addShipTax">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><b>Discount</b></td>
<td>$ <input type="text" name="discount" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><b>Total</b></td>
<td><span id="finalTotal">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var subtotal = $('#subTotal').text();
$('#addShipTax').text(subtotal * 11 / 100);

var discount = $('[name=discount]').val();
$('#finalTotal').text($('#addShipTax').text() - discount);
```

?

Comment: Thanks! I changed up the form a bit to break down the 5% and 6% and got it working. The only thing is that the (final) total doesn't reflect the discount when I input a number. I did try
`code`var discount = $('[name=discount]').val();

Comment: did you try to put the second half of the code I gave you inside the discount input keyup() event??

Comment: That would be it. Thanks!